# How to view the backup for a Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I created an export of my data (3 collections) in Firebase Firestore which ends up looking like this:
[image: Backup]

This is seen under: `https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser`

Now I have tried to import this data using Google BigQuery but I am not sure which of these outputs to use.

How can I view the data here? I basically want to verify that this export actually has data from my collections as it is not so obvious. Or is there something I am doing wrong with my export?

I basically ran this command: `gcloud firestore export gs://[MyBucketName]`

Comment: Google Big Data is not a product I know of. Do you mean BigQuery by any chance?

Comment: Hmm yeah sorry thats what I meant, will fix the post

Comment: Though it does not have to be BigQuery. I just want to somehow verify that the backup created properly as i cant see whats in the backup i created.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how detailed you want (or not) to verify the export, you could [import it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_all_documents_from_an_export) into another Cloud Firestore database.

This would be interesting if you just want to verify the export through some spot checks (i.e. checking a random limited number of documents and collections).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect the exported data with BigQuery you can follow the guide in [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore